# How can I log into my godaddy server, cd into my git repo and pull from origin master in one line from the terminal?

Tags: git, ssh, terminal

I type in from the terminal:

```
ssh username@domain.com 'cd git/repo && git pull origin master'
```

It then prompts me for a password (the password is to pull from github, it's not to ssh because I set up the key thingy).

But once I enter it in, it just hangs and doesn't do anything.

I googled all over the place. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to use the `-t` option for SSH to allocate a pseudo-TTY:

```
ssh -t username@domain.com 'cd git/repo && git pull origin master'
```

Answer (score 0):

### How vital is it that it needs to be on one line? One option would be to establish a variable to the result of the github command and then use that in the ssh command.

To set a variable to a command:

```
EXAMPLE = "$(YOUR COMMAND HERE)"
```

then to call the variable EXAMPLE:

```
$EXAMPLE
```

for you it might look like

```
PASS = "$(cd git/repo && git pull origin master)"

ssh username@domain.com $PASS`
```